# Как посмотреть исходный код программы?

Tags: c++, отладчик

Я хочу подправить исходный код, ничего серьезного, только вывод нескольких строк.
Программа написана скорее всего на С++. Мне использовать отладчик? Или как-то открыть в IDE? Просто я не хочу запускать программу, хочу просто поковыряться в коде. И может посоветуете какой нибудь? 
P.S. Сам файл - .exe

Comment: Если подправить exe 32-битный и знаю ассемблер/ понимаю запись строк и других данных в двоичном коде - скачайте `hiew.exe` (можно как править надписи, так и код)

Comment: @nick_n_a  А с notepad++ можно exeшники открывать? Или к  .exe применять 2 комментарий?

Comment: А я думал у вас исходный код в наличии.

Comment: @nick_n_a Нет, есть только .exe файл и все.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Исходный код раскрыть невозможно если для этого постарались обеспечить безопасность (особенно если это фирменная вещь).

Но есть способы полностью или частично раскрыть код.

- IDA Pro - самый лучший из безплатных взломщиков, некоторые макросы возможно позволяют преобразовать код назад. Но не всегда. Особо хорошо раскрываются borland-продукты.
- `Hiew.Exe` бесплатная утилита, очень маленькая, позволяет править код на языке ассемблера. Можно править текстовые и целые константы. Можно ею даже сделать "перевод" программы на другой язык, затереть имя фирмы и т.п.
- Если есть PDB-файл, или подшита debug-info к файлу то код можно получить в среде разработки (если debug-info полная) редко можно использовать. Исходный код получить нельзя, но можно получить "номера строк и имена исходников", а так же имена/значения всех констант, локальных переменных, избежать "раздроблености функций" а так же получить классы с начинкой класса (почти все структуры кроме текста программы) что значительно упростит понимание работы программы. Для некоторых библиотек (dll) pdb-файлы можно скачать отдельно. Врядли уважающая себя фирма допустит утечку pdb своего стоящего продукта.
- Debug info, существует DebugInfo-информация встроеная в exe. Если есть такая информация, и соответствующая утилита (Например на Borland Delphi собран, и он есть в наличии), то можно сделать аналогичное предыдущему пункту. Но врядли уважающая себя фирма допустит такую "глупую" ошибку (аналогично pdb).
- Если файл написан на с# его можно почти полностью просмотреть в кодах с помощью disSharp (такие программы "подключают" в таблице импорта лишь mscorlib и всё). DisSharp плохо дизассемблирует некоторые части программы, но возможно его платная версия или платная версия подобных утилит раскрывает код лучше.
- Если файл написан на FoхPro, clipper и других подобный байт-кодовых языках - он раскрывается спец-утилитами (Refox например).
- Утилита `exescope.exe` `ResourceHacker.exe` и её-подобные утилиты позволяют смотреть шапку, подключенные библиотеки (по ним можно **понять** на чём писана программа) и редактировать ресурсы программы (ресурс-формы в.т.ч. delphi, иконки, картинки, таблицы ресурсо-строк).
- Если извесно чем создан код - думаю есть специальные утилиты способные его раскрыть (они платные и малодоступные).

Опять-же, это при условии что нету паковщика кода (тогда нужно сначала применить депаковщик), шифровальщика/самомодифицирующегося кода. Если не разбит обфускатором так что не распутать. Чем больше код - тем сложнее разобраться.

P.S. Лично моё мнение - раскрывается-взламывается всё, но на это нужно потратить много-много времени. Возможно год и более (зависит от опыта и инструментов, в свободном доступе хороших инструментов нету).

Comment: Не думаю что он зашифрован. Хотя... Все дело в том, что это довольно известный вирус.

Comment: Тогда только IDA

Comment: А что делать с .exe написанном на Паскале?

Comment: `Паскаль` и `с` в итоге выглядят практически одинаково. Всё в ассемблере, так что её можно восстановить в код `с` (теоретически)

Comment: "Если есть PDB-файл, или подшита debug-info к файлу то код можно получить в среде разработки.". В среде разработки можно будет получить только имена исходных файлов и номера строк. Самого кода таким способом вы не получите.

Answer (score 5):

Рад буду ошибаться, что такого способа для "новичка" просто нет. 
Вам нужно дизассемблеровать exe-файл в IDA или Hiew32, ну и там уже рассматривать код на языке asm(низкого уровня).

Comment: Я открываю с Hiew32, и открывается ка будто  обычным блокнотом открыл, просто  побитая кодировка.

Comment: @антонсорокин
Жмете f4, выбираете там раздел Decode, дальше уже в гугл и в тех.литературу, ибо увиденное едва ли будет вам понятно. Способ не простой. Дизассемблирование вещь невероятно сложная, но если так интересно, то можете почитать книги Криса Касперски.

Answer (score 1):

В двух словах - это невозможно. Запускаемая программа - это результат компиляции исходного кода в некоторый набор машинных инструкций. Обратный процесс невозможен, разве что вы проанализируете машинный код и сами по нему воссоздадите исходник.

Comment: Вопрос спорный, и ответ именно в таком случае тоже спорный. Т.к. в отдельных случаях код можно раскрыть, если писали определёнными средствами.